# Self-boost charge pump for high-side driving: how to drive the high-side driver itself?

Tags: high-voltage, mosfet-driver, charge-pump, high-side

This is the circuit:

[image]

My question is: how can I send signals to the high-side MOSFET driver?

I thought about this way:

[image]

But "B" may be 0 V when the MOSFET is on, resulting in a negative voltage on the driver's input (assuming the input's ground is high voltage)

Am I right? If I'm right, how can I drive the high-side driver properly?

EDIT:

What do you guys think about this way (added in green - resistor voltage divider and a fast diode), will it work?

[image]

How do they do it in their ICs? Isn't it called "level shifting"?

Comment: You could use one of the many chips that are designed to do this job.

Comment: @Andyaka Can't find one which is able to provide high output currents (greater than 2A)

Comment: IRS2181 is 1.5/1.8A, is that enough? How about LF2110BTR, LF21904NTR, FAN7393A, etc.? The charge pump can be added onto any bootstrap type driver just fine.

Comment: @TimWilliams thanks for the suggestions but still not enough current for my needs, that's why I'm trying to make it from discrete components and the charge pump part works well, now I'm just trying to figure out how to drive the high side driver properly, the driver I'm gonna use at the high side is TC4451 which is able to sink 12A, all I need is just a way to drive this driver properly...

Comment: 12A?!  Just what are you doing? Is bootstrap really the best way to go here?

Comment: @Tim  There's nothing fundamentally wrong with a 12A peak gate current.  The gate drive pulse is brief.  The large(ish) value may be due to a large geometry of the gate, or multiple IGBTs in parallel.

Comment: @NickAlexeev Not by itself no, but it suggests context that may be relevant. The only thing I've driven with that much current is IGBT modules. Which have enough current flow, and stray inductance, that bootstrap drivers simply aren't usable. They need higher drive voltages too, in particular, negative Vge(off), which none of these types can do.

Comment: @TimWilliams Is there a way to do it which is not bootstrap? I'm not familiar with other ways, what do you suggest?

Comment: @lidorov19, what are you doing -- what IGBTs, voltage, current, speed, control (generally about the control, like is it complicated enough or connected to enough other things that isolation would be useful?), etc.?

Comment: @TimWilliams Power Inverter for simple household items use  , 330V , 20A , 20Khz PWM , IPZ65R019C7 - this MOSFET is driven by TC4451 which is driven by logic gates output  , at the output of the inverter there is a sine wave filter and a full wave rectifier with a high pass filter to sense any sudden drops in voltage , that's it .

Comment: Oh not even IGBTs then. But that MOSFET is only 215nC Qg, if you even manage to get 10A peak into it that's a 21ns gate transition time, meanwhile the drain will take hundreds to swing at that load current, if not hard switching. What are you really doing by being so fast?

Comment: @TimWilliams ,
What do you mean by "if you even manage to get 10A peak into it" ? 
and what do you mean by "meanwhile the drain will take hundreds to swing at that load current" ?
I'm trying to make this inverter compact , meaning - without fast fans and big heatsinks , so I need to lower the switching losses , that's why I thought about driving it with a lot of current .

Comment: You may find using such oversized transistors ends up costing much more in hard switching or even body diode recovery losses.  And hard switching loss does not depend on gate switching speed. At 20kHz, switching losses will likely be a very small part of total cost; core loss and inductor size will dominate.

Comment: @TimWilliams I want to thank you , you said I was wrong about switching with 12A and you didn't want to explain it to me thoroughly because you saw that I was stupid , you didn't say I am stupid , I'm now saying I was , but now I understand it , thank you for trying to warn me .
btw do you think PWM in an open loop (no feedback) is a bad idea ?

Comment: Not wrong, per se, more likely misguided, or not well considered. There may be cases where that combination (10A+ drive on a transistor that size) is needed; this just doesn't seem to be one, given what you've told. And yes, open loop is a bad idea: how will you regulate the output? How will it handle reactive, or nonlinear loads? How will you handle startup or fault conditions? Perhaps this would make a good new question topic, if you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [MOSFET driver you are using](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/20001987C.pdf) is mostly designed for low side gate drive, but with a separate boost charge pump, you will probably need to use a high speed optocoupler.

But you might be able to use a high side driver like [LTC7001](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/LTC7001.pdf) and use its output to drive your TC4451.